# Problem with UV Mapping in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I recently started having problems with UV mapping. I map the object on the same color yet it has different shades of the color. For example I was mapping a car I'm making for a game and it looked like this.

The interior of that car should all be one gray but it ends up as different shades of gray and some brown even though they are all on the same part of the texture (the texture is only 9 px by 9 px).
[image: model with incorrect colors in side]

[image: model and texture]

Comment: We'll need more details including screen shots of your uv maps etc.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/afe9c9a12550690ee50177c3a4b1855a it's only 9x9 pixels, it's small for the game

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What did you expect it to look like, and how does that differ from what you're seeing?

Comment: The interior of that car should all be one gray but it ends up as different shades of gray and some brown even though they are all on the same part of the map

Answer (score 0):

Try  pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) in edit mode of the mesh while all the mesh is selected, that will recalculate all the normals, also very important press (<kbd>T</kbd>) and in edit mode of the mesh while all the mesh is selected find button Remove Doubles. If non of this work try unwrapping the object again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26419/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-tatarnikov-problem-with-uv-mapping-in-cycles).